# adding constants together in a single method with if statements

Tags: java, constants

I am trying to create a single method that adds points if a player meets certain criteria

the base rate for all players is 60

if  greater than 74 inches tall and 190 pounds heavy is 5

if scores goals true is 4

if drinks beer true is - 10

I don't know how to add the constants together in a single method but I could do it by creating multiple methods

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int height;
private double weight;
private boolean scoresGoal;
private boolean drinksBeer;

public static final int BASE_RATE = 60;
public static final int TALL_INCHES = 74;
public static final double HEAVY_POUNDS = 190.0;
public static final int TALL_HEAVY_BONUS = 5;
public static final int SCORES_BONUS = 4; 
public static final int DRINKS_DEDUCTION = 10;

public int calculateGamePay() {

    return BASE_RATE + getTALL_HEAVY_BONUS() + getSCORES_BONUS() - getDRINKS_DEDUCTION();

}

public int getTALL_HEAVY_BONUS(){

    if(height >= 74 && weight >= 190) { 

       return TALL_HEAVY_BONUS;

    } else{  

       return 0;

    }

}

public int getSCORES_BONUS(){

    if(scoresGoal == true) {

        return SCORES_BONUS;

    } else {

        return 0;

    }

}

public int getDRINKS_DEDUCTION(){

    if(drinksBeer == true) {

        return DRINKS_DEDUCTION;

    } else {

        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: There is nothing impropriate to calculate this parameters in different methods, it makes code readable.

Comment: true. But I think my teacher told me to use only one method to do this. I am not sure if I remember correctly. I have been trying to think of a way to use only one method.

Comment: I won't write it for you, but you can do it with using default value and increasing and decreasing this value based on each if statements. You can write it in one method.

Comment: Sidenote. Use `if (scoresGoal)` instead of `if (drinksBeer == true)`. Try using ternary operator for simple if-else e.g. 
`public int getSCORES_BONUS(){ 
  return scoresGoal ? SCORES_BONUS : 0;
}`

I agree with @UladzislauKaminski about code readibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three `if` statements in your `calculateGamePay` method to add or subtract points from a starting amount of `BASE_RATE`.

```
public int calculateGamePay() {
    int pay = BASE_RATE;
    if(height >= 74 && weight >= 190) pay += TALL_HEAVY_BONUS;
    if(scoresGoal) pay += SCORES_BONUS;
    if(drinksBeer) pay -= DRINKS_DEDUCTION;
    return pay;
}
```

Alternatively, you can combine the logic of all three of your methods into one line using the ternary operator.

```
public int calculateGamePay() {
    return BASE_RATE + (height >= 74 && weight >= 190 ? TALL_HEAVY_BONUS : 0)
        + (scoresGoal ? SCORES_BONUS : 0) - (drinksBeer ? DRINKS_DEDUCTION: 0);
}
```

Comment: Please do not actually use ternary operators in this way, it creates code that is understandable to literally nobody.